Following up in a friendly exchange
I have been out of work and study for quite a long time, and have also decided to move country a couple of months ago. I dropped into the local Zoology Collection to enquire about volunteering opportunities in this area, and I got to meet with the head of the department I am most interested in. I told him about what I'd been doing for the past few years, and I think he gets the gist that I'd like to work in this area one day (I have a bachelor in Zoology). He said I could do some voluntary work as part of one of his projects and that I should email him again in a couple of weeks. In the resulting exchange fee asked when I'd be free, and I told him the next day which days of the following week I'd be free. However it is now within a couple of days within the time I suggested, and he hasn't replied. Apologies for asking on here, but being out of work/study for a while I am just a little anxious. Is the following ok:
"Hallo X
I just wanted to check whether I will get anything to work on this week.
Kind regards,
Y"
And I was thinking of sending this as part of the original email chain (not a new one).
Many thanks for any/all advice!

This is more a workplace issue than an academic one.

@Buffy where I am at is that I'd like to work toward getting a job at the level of a technician. If I understand the situation correctly, the kind of computer-based voluntary work he is offering seems to have the potential to develop into something similar to an unpaid internship (I believe he asked me whether I would be any good in data analysis for example). He is active in academic research as far as I understand.

I'd err on the side of being a bit more polite and formal.
Dear First/last name (whatever you parted on last time in your exchange),
I'm following up on my e-mail from xxx (see below), as I am still super excited to xxx. Could you please let me know when I can drop by?
Kind regards,
Yourname
And then, if you don't hear from him in another few days, try calling. Old school, but effective.
